# How to check if form file field is empty in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

Hi I would like to know how can i check if file field is empty and form is submitted.

I want to add check right after form submission and send error to user that "Please Select File"

Comment: Is this a form mapped to an Entity?

Comment: Try the [File](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html) constraint.

Comment: no it is just a csv file upload field and then process in controller no mapping to an entity

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the following code:

```
$file = $form['csv']->getData();    

if (!is_object($file))
    $this->get('Ras.Alert.AlertReportingService')->addError('alerts.form.fileempty');

else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('file', 'file', [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(['message' => 'Please select file']),
            new File(['mimeTypes' => 'text/csv', 'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload only csv files'])
        ]
    ])
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // Process form
}
```